# Is it misleading to say "holes in semiconductors jump to the other side"?

Tags: transistors, semiconductors

I'm getting a little confused with the convention of saying that "holes in a semiconductor will move from p-side to n-side and electrons will move the opposite way". I have no trouble with the concept itself, it just seems to me that an electron moving from one side to the other would mean it left a hole behind where it used to be?

Am I understanding it correct that we just think of electrons leaving behind holes as "holes moving" or do I actually misinterperet the way this works?

Comment: think of a row of seats at a theatre .... one empty seat in the middle ... one empty seat at one end ... two people arrive and ask everyone to move one seat over ... if the people move one at a time, then that empty seat in the middle of of the row can be thought of as travelling to the end of the row

Comment: ...and sometimes there is an extra person (donor atom) standing in a row. When that person moves they don't leave a hole behind. A hole is not simply the result of an electron moving, it is an electron leaving a covalent bond in the silicon lattice.

Comment: @jsotola I understand this concept, but I still think it would be silly to describe something that is literally the abscence of something as "moving". Isn't this just more confusing or is it actually useful to think this way?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson But for a hole to "move", an electron always have to leave, right?

Comment: @MariusGulbrandsen A lot of people like the "a hole is just the absence of an electron" model, but I find it to be confusing, and therefore a bad model, for the reasons you have stated. It also isn't an accurate description of what is happening.

Comment: The electrons vs holes thing is to teach the concept without having to detour too deep into material physics. It works for getting the point across but lacks the math to fully describe how it will behave with all materials.

Comment: Yes, for a hole to form an electron must move but the reverse is not true. An electron can move without forming a hole.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Electrons and holes are two different types of charge carrier in a semiconductor. They obey the same set of rules, electrons aren't special. You can't change the electron population without also changing the hole population. Holes moving does not necessitate the movement of electrons. If it did, the Hall effect would not work as it does.

Comment: Most popular and duplicate questions in ESE: holes and electrons , ground and earth :D  closing all the way ...xD

Comment: @Matt Electrons and holes are different types of charge carrier??? Thanks for clearing that up. I didn't say anything about changing the electron **population**, I said that electrons could **move** without needing the movement of holes. In silicon doped with a donor there are electrons that are not held in covalent bonds. These electrons are able to move without creating holes (empty covalent bonds).

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Your previous, and current, statement are unclear. You seem to be saying things that nobody questions, which makes me think you are meaning something else. Neither electrons not holes are not special. The same rules apply to both. Holes can also **move** without needing the movement of electrons. In silicon doped with acceptors there are free holes that are able to move without creating free electrons. This is standard semiconductor theory. What are you trying to say?

Comment: @Matt I didn't say that the movement of a hole required the movement of a **free** electron or the creation of a **free** electron. You are changing the meaning of my statements and misinterpreting them. The basis of my statements is that an electron is a physical particle while a hole is an unfilled covalent bond in the silicon crystal lattice. I didn't say that either was "special" or that different "rules" applied to them. If you take the position that a hole **is** an actual physical particle (and not just "effectively the same") then we're done here.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson The only electrons that move are free electrons, I changed nothing by including the word "free". Even if that were not the case your claims are still contradicting the results of a Hall measurement. A hole in a semiconductor is exactly as real as an electron. Both are abstractions of the electric field within a crystal lattice structure of semiconductors. If you want to keep claiming that holes are just movement of missing electrons I strongly suggest you brush up on your understanding of the band structure of semiconductors and the Hall effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your quote it sounds like you are learning about charge carrier diffusion in a P-N junction. When those electrons and holes diffuse they don't leave behind a mobile charge carrier of the opposite type. They do however leave behind an ionized dopant atom, which is a fixed charge of the opposite type.

---

When dealing with semiconductors we two different mobile charge carriers: electrons and holes, as well as two energy bands where they can exist: valence and conduction. When talking about electrons and holes in a semiconductor, we mean electrons in the conduction band, and holes in the valence band. When these carriers are in the other band, they don't contribute to conduction, so we ignore them.

Many people like to think of a hole as a missing electron, but I think that is a bad description of the system for a few reasons. First, it is important to treat electrons and holes separately as their own individual particles. You can't rewrite all of semiconductor physics to work with just one carrier type (you probably can, but it would be much more complicated) Second, as previously mentioned, electrons and holes contribute to current when they are in different energy bands. So, a hole in the valence band moving is very much not the same thing as an electron in the conduction band moving in the opposite direction. In fact, the [Hall effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect) relies on this to be the case.

> Am I understanding it correct that we just think of electrons leaving behind holes as "holes moving" or do I actually misinterperet the way this works?

You can generate an electron-hole pair by moving an electron from the valence band to the conduction band, which results in +1 electron in the conduction band, and also +1 hole in the valence band. But from your quote it sounds like you are talking about carrier diffusion. In which case, no, electrons and holes moving around within a single band do not leave behind a carrier of the other type. They might, however, leave behind an ionized dopant atom, which is a fixed charge.

You are going to have a much easier time with semiconductor physics if you think of holes as just another type of particle, similar to electrons but with a positive charge (and a different mass).

---

To address some concerns from the comments I have included here some quotes from Solid State Physics by Ashcroft and Mermin page 227-228. This discussion relates to where holes come. Once you determine your material's electronic band structure you may do the following:

> It therefore suffices to examine how electrons respond to applied fields to learn how holes do. The motion of an electron is determined by the semiclassical equation:
>
> \$\hbar \mathbf{\dot k}=(-e)\left(\mathbf E+\frac{1}{c}\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf H\right)\$  (12.22)
>
> Whether or not the orbit of the electron resembles that of a free particle of negative charge depends on whether the acceleration , \$d\mathbf v/dt\$, is or is not parallel to \$\mathbf{\dot k}\$. Should the acceleration be opposite to \$\mathbf{\dot k}\$, then the electron would respond more like a positively charged free particle. As it happens, it is often the case that \$d\mathbf{v}/dt\$ is indeed directed opposite to \$\mathbf{\dot k}\$ when \$\mathbf{k}\$ is the wave vector of an unoccupied level

It goes on to explain why this happens which is outside the scope of this question, and ends with:

> we find that as long as an electron's orbit is confined to levels close enough to the band maximum for the expansion (12.23) to be accurate, the (negatively charged) electron responds to driving fields as if it had a negative mass \$-m^*\$. By simply changing the sign of both sides, we can equally well (and far more intuitively) regard Eq (12.22) as describing the motion of a positively charged particle with a positive mass \$m^*\$.

So yes, the electron/hole model allows for you to look at the system as two different particles of the same charge, but one has a negative mass, or you can model the system as two particles with the same sign mass, but opposite sign charges.

The takeaway is still that electrons and holes are two different things and the "holes are just missing electrons" model is inaccurate and does not work (again, see the Hall effect).

Comment: Whats the numeric value of charge of hole? If it's a different particle, then I believe it should have some charge and positive charge of course. I once had the same confusion. The teacher just told me that hole is a positive charge but I found it to be a vacant space. I can see your good explanation why this concept is misleading but what if I want to measure the charge of hole?

Comment: @JuneStar The charge of a hole is the same as the charge of an electron, but positive: 1.602e-19 C. Holes are more real than a lot of people give them credit for. They show up at the quantum level in a semiconductor and are just as real as the free electrons in the semiconductor. (Another valid interpretation of the results of the quantum model is a particle with a negative charge and a negative mass. But we decided that positive charges make more sense than negative masses.) Im not sure about measuring their charge. I could divise some tests but they all make some assumptions.

Comment: Can holes exist when there is no any movement of electrons?

Comment: @JuneStar We cant really have "no movement of electrons" at any temperature above 0 K. An electric field that would cause holes to move will also cause electrons to move. Concentration gradients cant exist in only one carrier type either. But its not the electron movement thats enabling hole movement. You can shrink the electron concentration to be many orders of magnitude below the hole concentration. Then you will effectively have (net) hole movement without electron (net) movement, verified by Hall measurements.

Comment: But if you take away your parenthetical "(net)" qualification, the movement of an individual hole requires the movement of an individual electron. Don't confuse the movement of individual carriers with a change in their concentration.

Comment: @ElluotAlderson The "(net)" is there to be pedantic because free charge carriers are very quickly moving all over the place. You are absolutely wrong that movement of a hole requires movement of an electron, it does not. See the Hall effect. It absolutely requires two carrier types: one with a positive charge and one with a negative charge. In your version there would be no such effect. Im not conflating charge carrier movement and changes in concentration, now or before. I was describing a way you could have nearly no electrons in your semiconductor for maximum hole movement.

Comment: Sorry, my model of semiconductor physics does not include a particle with negative mass. If that's part of your model of conduction then I don't think we can really have a conversation. Peace unto you.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Correct. Which is why I said the interpretation we use of the results of a quantum analysis of a semiconductor has particles with both signs in charge rather than in mass. Clearly from your response you are out of your depth in this subject. I suggest you pick up a copy of "Solid State Physics" by Ashcroft and Mermin, or another similar text. Which goes into great detail about this.

Comment: @elliot : Intuitive models of quantum phenomena are often misleading.

Comment: For clarification, if an electron enters a hole, and the hole has a charge, does that mean the hole has to move somewhere else? If not, what happens to the charge the hole had?

Comment: @Marius The only time an electron enters a hole is when they recombine and their charges cancel out. During normal electron or hole current no electrons are entering holes and no holes are entering electrons.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I added a reference. I hope this clears things up.

Answer (score 2):

Both 'hole' and 'electron' are models for what actually happens. It turns out that they can both be modelled as a quantum mechanical 'particle'. These are the best / easiest models to to use to understand semiconductor operation.

However, 'electron' is rather closer to our limited classical touchy-feely idea of reality than 'hole' is, which is why more of us grok electrons than holes.

> Am I understanding it correct that we just think of electrons leaving behind holes as "holes moving" or do I actually misinterperet the way this works?

I think the biggest problem with your question there is the word 'just'. No, it's not 'just' this, it's much more complicated.